# Is setting virtual memory to a level higher than normal dangerous to the system?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

I currently have 6GB of physical RAM installed in my PC and I lag in Fortnite so I decided to go to virtual memory and put it to 50,000 (which is 50GB) and apparently it takes that from my hard drive which is not a big deal cause I have loads of space. I have a 500GB hard disk drive.

So is this dangerous or is it fine? Like it helped my game alot I dont lag at all. But if it is dangerous what damage would it do?

Comment: Additionally virtual memory won’t solve latency issues In Fortnite.  No; It’s not dangerous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fine.

> So is this dangerous or is it fine? Like it helped my game alot I dont
>   lag at all. But if it is dangerous what damage would it do?

Regardless of what you set virtual memory (paging file size) to, the OS will work hard to keep active portions of memory in RAM.  As Fortnight consumes more RAM, more less-active portions of memory will be "paged out" to disk.  This is great.

In fairness, the OS isn't perfect, and you could see some lag if the OS pages out something relevant to the game by accident.  If so, quit other (non-Fortnight) programs that are running and try again.  It is hard to believe that whatever result would be worse than if you didn't have the page file.

As far as damage, you will not damage your computer by adjusting this setting.  You could conceivably set the page file size high enough that you'd run out of disk space for saving data, but it sounds like you aren't at risk of that right now.  Keep in mind that a page file can exist on each drive letter, and will count against that disk's capacity.

Good luck with your game!

Answer (score -4):

It's not dangerous, but it is most likely counterproductive. Hard disk is orders of magnitude slower then RAM. Using disk at space can cause things to go very slow.

Comment: The words "take that from my Hard Drive" in the question? That he has "loads of space" and "6gigs of memory" are entirely consistent with that assertion.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if down voters advised what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: @JakeGould - regardless of SSD or HDD the answer is largely similar. SSD is much faster then HDD but still an order of magnitude or 2 slower then RAM. Wear does come into it, but is unlikely to massively impact the answer especially on a very large SSD which will have more blocks to handle wear levelling.

Comment: There's a fundamental misunderstanding at the core of this answer: the swap aspect of virtual memory doesn't get used *unnecessarily*.  If large amounts of swap are being used, then the system is trying to slowly do something *it could not do at all* without that.  Otherwise the allocated but unused virtual memory will just sit there.

Comment: I downvoted for reasons similar to those expressed by Chris S (though I don't think s/he downvoted). This "answer"  belies a fundamental misunderstanding of virtual memory. You're _always_ using virtual memory. Having a larger pagefile than necessary does not encourage any more of it to be kept in the pagefile.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan How sure of that are you? I know for a fact that the size of the swap file in Linux impacts the kernel decisions on how much/what to swap (influenced by VM.swappiness etc) and I would be astounded if Windows did not make use of more swap if it were.made available - especially as this worked in the case of the OP.

Comment: 100%. Windows does not allow you to create more private virtual address space (which is the sort that is backed by the pagefile) than can be contained by RAM + the pagefile. If you try it you'll get "out of memory" errors. Having more pagefile space than is absolutely needed for all private v.a.s. would allow the OS to keep more of the _other_ v.a.s. (the stuff that's backed by other than the pagefile) in RAM, but that's not the same as "encouraging" more use of the pagefile.

Comment: otoh, making sure the pagefile has a lot of free space can allow the pagefile routines to work a little faster, mostly by reducing internal fragmentation.